# iOS 8 - autoresizing cells don't always show all label text

Tags: uitableview, ios8, autoresize

basically I'm using autoresizing custom table view cells to display data on a table view and they resize perfectly, usually. The cells have a `UILabel` on them to display the data and the cells autoresize if the devices text size is changed. I'm sometimes having troubles with the cells autoresizing to show all of the `UILabel`'s text. For example if the text size is medium sized, it sometimes doesn't fully display all the text of a longer label, it will show most of it then show "..." but if I increase or decrease the text size it will show it all but it might do the same thing for a different cell.

Any suggestions? Here's my code that calls the autoresize:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    [self retrieveFromParse];

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

}
```

and to autoresize depending on text size:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    _cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (_cell == nil)
    {
        _cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    PFObject *object = [_postsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *nameString = [object objectForKey:@"Name"];

    _cell.cellLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Posted by %@", nameString];
    _cell.cellPostLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"   %@", [object objectForKey:@"Post"]];

    //The following lines are to auto resize when the text size is changed

    _cell.cellLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleFootnote];
    _cell.cellPostLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleSubheadline];

    return _cell;

}
```

Comment: Are your labels multi-line?

Comment: They are. And the cells height is autoresized depending on the height (the amount of lines) of the `_cell.cellPostLabel`. The label displays a post that was made in a different view controller and has a max character size of 199 so they aren't too excessively long.

Comment: Correction: They can be multi-lined, it depends on how much text they contain. Some might not be but most are.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **autoresizingMask** if that helps

```
_cell.cellLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but no dice. I even tried `_cell.cellPostLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;` as well as `_cell.cellPostLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin` I thought that might work because the cells height is autoresized depending on the `_cellPostLabel`'s height, but still nothing. Maybe the `preferredFontForTextStyle:` methods are contradicting it?

Answer (score 0):

Auto Layout has trouble figuring out how to draw multi-line labels if you don't set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` on each one.  The trouble is finding out what value to use since tables can change widths across the various iPhone & iPad devices, orientations, etc.  To fix this, I usually subclass `UILabel` to override `layoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews]; // 1

    self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds); // 2

    [super layoutSubviews]; // 3
}
```

1. The first call to `super` correctly determines how wide the label should be.
2. Using the correct width, set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to the correct value.
3. Do another layout pass to render the label with its final and correct properties.

Comment: This works but not immediately when the view appears, only when I scroll down so the label is off screen then scroll back up to it, then it is fixed and the full label content is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use autolayout, I have solution for you. I'm not sure that this is the perfect one, but here it is (Swift):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    // configure your cell
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()      
}
```

P.S. if I doesn't use layoutIfNeeded and if I rotate my device and turn it back, to portrait, label layouts as it must e.g. 2 or more strings in one cell.

Didn't find reason why this occur, because (I use more that one prototype cell in my project) other type cells is okay, but their labels have simular constraints and settings.

Answer (score -1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 66
}
```

works just fine on 8.4.1 for UITableViewCellStyle.Default cells